# PHP Script Unable to Read Image File Type

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

I'm working on a project which includes uploading images. I notice that while Javascript can easily read the file type (e.g. image/jpeg), PHP was flunking a lot of images it should have read.
This is my HTML

```html
<form action="page.php" style="margin:10rem" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" />
  <button type="submit" value="Go">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
    $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    echo "File type is " . $type . "<br>";

    if($_FILES['image']['error']){
      echo "Error is " .$_FILES['image']['error'];
    }
}
```

And some Javascript to alert the file type selected:

```js
  $('body').on('change', 'input', function(){
    var files = this.files[0];
    alert(files.type);
  })
```

I tried uploading a 2.81 MB jpeg file. Javascript alerts the type as "image/jpeg", but PHP doesn't return the expected "File type is image/jpeg". Instead, it executes the error block of code and echoes "1" [Whatever that means]. I need to know WHY PHP ISN'T ABLE TO READ FILE TYPE OF SOME JPEG IMAGES. It's not the size, I know, because it may accept an image of 3.78 MB, but refuse a 2.81MB jpeg image. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the error that is received when uploading the 2.81 image?

Comment: _“[Whatever that means]”_ ... is explained in the manual, so go read up on it!  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Please find image type using from this code:
`var FileUploadPath = this.files[0].value;
 var Extension = FileUploadPath.substring(FileUploadPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();`

Comment: @misorude, I read it. Turns out I needed to increase the maximum file upload size in my php.ini file. Thanks a lot.